# Calculate floor of $\frac{1}{x_1 + 1} + \frac{1}{x_2 + 1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_{100} + 1}$

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

There is a recurrence sequence $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + x_n$. How much is floor of $\frac{1}{x_1 + 1} + \frac{1}{x_2 + 1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_{100} + 1}$? Floor is an integer part of a real number.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x_n+1}$ and $x_3 > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructive hints of @AchilleHui deserve an answer by its own.

> Given the recurrence relation 
>   \begin{align*}
> x_{n+1}&=x_n(x_n+1)\tag{1}\\
> x_1&=\frac{1}{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> we derive from (1) a telescoping representation of the reciprocal values via
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{x_{n+1}}&=\frac{1}{x_n(x_n+1)}
> =\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x_n+1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{x_j+1}&=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{x_j}-\frac{1}{x_{j+1}}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{x_j}-\sum_{j=2}^{101}\frac{1}{x_j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_{101}}\\
> &=2-\frac{1}{x_{101}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> From $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and (1) we get $x_2=\frac{3}{4}, x_3=\frac{21}{16}>1$ and it follows again from (1) $x_n>1$ with $n\geq 3$.
>
> We finally get from (2) 
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left\lfloor 2-\frac{1}{x_{101}} \right\rfloor = 1}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* Since $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_{n+1}\approx x_n^2$ we have $x_{101}\approx \frac{1}{2^{2^{100}}}$. So, the difference of $2-\frac{1}{x_{101}}$ to the value $2$ is very small.

Comment: For all practical purposes, this sums to 2, but since it is less than 2 by some finite (though unimaginably small) amount, the floor is 1.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Thanks for the credit. That's why I've added the note. We have to carefully consider precision settings when doing numerical calculations. This is a good example showing that $\pm 1$ errors might occur relatively easy. This could lead to problematic situations when used in critical code sections.

Comment: I see. I think what confused me was saying that the difference is small, when in fact the difference is nearly 2.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Thanks, wording corrected.